# How to populate a site column from a list to another list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have defined a couple of lists for capturing registration details of the user. There is a list for holding personal details of the user and there is another list which holds professional details of the user.
The two lists are used over two different pages in which name and ID both are required.
How do I get the name and ID populated automatically into the professional list from personal list so as the user doesn't have to fill the similar information twice?
Is it possible without doing any coding stuff?

Answer (score 0):

This little control may help you

http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/

Basically you would link the first Cascading drop down control to your user details list and the field name. The second drop down would then filter the users ID so the user can select that.

I have used this before and it can be a pain in the backside to configure but when it's there it is so very powerful and useful.

It's not fully automated but i'm unsure how you would get any closer with a bespoke event receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom form there, you have keep some text box with the refresh button, so when ever you fill the user id and press the refresh button. You need to right small logic to bring the user from the the source list.

Or you can use the personal details id as look up column in the prop list so you will get the id and select the id and do refresh. Anyway you have right the logic in your custom form code.